# How do you get indented text except for the first line of a paragraph

Tags: indentation

Something like :

```
First line of a praragraph followed by
  indented text and some
  more indented text
```

In other words the inverse of what you usually get. MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hangindent

Comment: I think this can be solved by `\hangindent`, but I cant get it to work.

Comment: I used the solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328615/hangindent-repeated-for-each-paragraph Thanks to @DavidCarlisle