# Manual tab inside \textit mode

Tags: indentation

[image: Output]

[image: Input]

I'm wondering how I can manually tab the second line? I've tried `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\tab`, and `\hspace` already. In the second imagine, I tried to manually put in a tab with all the options above by using a new line as well.

Comment: What does "manually tab the second line" mean here? Do you want to indent the second line? See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328619/134144

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you want to do, but one easy way to get the second line indented is to use a description environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{description}
        \item[\mdseries\sf Author One, Author Two ``Title''] \textit{Long line that shall break 
            and be indented in all following lines for this item.} 
            That is, all lines, and not just the first. Some additional filler text 
            so it is long enough...
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: example: indent lines using description]

Also, a BibTeX bibliography might be the right tool for the job here, so make sure to check that out. But this is a way to do it manually, like you asked for.